# Conditionally remove a word from a string?

Tags: php

I've found answers that are ***similar*** to the one I'm looking for, but not one that completely addresses my problem.

A user clicks a link on my page which takes them to Google Books and does a search.  However, if the first word in the title of the book contains a contraction, everything gets thrown off and none of my corrections seem to work.

Example:
The link on my page looks like this:

```
mysite.com/book-search?bookauthor=Lance Armstrong&booktitle=It's Not About the Bike
```

However, when I run this:

```
$bookTitle = $_GET['booktitle']
```

I get the same title with the apostrophe in "It's" removed.  And that's enough to completely throw off the Google Books Search and return no results.

The endpoint in the cURL session that does the search looks like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:' . $bookTitle . '+inauthor:' . $bookAuthor;
```

Try it yourself -

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:It%27s+Not_About+The+Bike+inauthor:Lance+Armstrong

Returns a completely different result than

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:Its+Not_About+The+Bike+inauthor:Lance+Armstrong

You'd think that if I urlencoded the strings, that would solve the problem.  But it doesn't.  Still, for a reason that I can't fathom, when I do this:

```
$google_endpoint_a = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:' . urlencode($bookTitle) . '+inauthor:' . urlencode($bookAuthor);
```

...the urlencoding gets stripped out when it's passed to the GoogleAPI and I get a zero result search again.

Can somebody help me wade through this?  I've tried everything I can think of.

**OH - and here's the bonus** - this ONLY happens if the first word in the string contains the apostrophe.  So it happens with book titles like "It's Not About The Bike" and "Don't Blink".  Apostrophes in other words don't seem to matter.  (Like author Bill O'Reilly, for example.)

Is there an easy way to remove the first word from the string IF it contains an apostrophe?  Or is there a better way?

***The Really Ugly Solution:***

So PHP passes $_GET variables through urldecode().  So even though it's ugly, here's what I ended up doing that solved the problem, even though I hope someone will come up with a better way.

Before I passed the variable through the URL, I replaced the apostrophe with a string of gibberish, like this:

```
$booktitle = str_replace("'", "W5x32RS97", $booktitle);
```

Then ran this:

```
$bookTitleTemp = $_GET('booktitle');
$bookTitle = str_replace("W5x32RS97", "'", $bookTitleTemp);
```

And suddenly, everything works.  But there's GOT to be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Hadn't you try to subtitute the ' by \' in your title string? I mean, instead of:
It's Not About the Bike, using this: It\'s Not About the Bike

Comment: That doesn't work either.  Only things that work are if Google's API gets either the apostrophe left in, or a %27 instead of the apostrophe.

(That's why included the links to the API calls, in case anyone wanted to try out different combinations.)

Answer (score 1):

Without the apostrophe, you can drop `intitle:` and just use the following string:

```
$google_endpoint_a = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' . urlencode($bookTitle) . '+inauthor:' . urlencode($bookAuthor);
```

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Its+Not_About+The+Bike&inauthor:Lance+Armstrong

**Update**

To write a condition to use `intitle` if the first word has an apostrophe, you can do something like:

```
$pieces = explode(" ", $bookTitle);

if (strpos($pieces[0], "'") !== FALSE) {
    $google_endpoint_a = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' . urlencode($bookTitle) . '+inauthor:' . urlencode($bookAuthor);
}
else {
    $google_endpoint_a = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=intitle:' . urlencode($bookTitle) . '+inauthor:' . urlencode($bookAuthor);
}
```

I would also see if encoding the variables earlier would work:

```
$bookTitle = urlencode($_GET[booktitle]);
```

Comment: Genius.  That works great.  (For that query.)

Is there a way to make it conditional?  If the first word contains the apostrophe, drop the "intitle"?

Comment: I see one of the issues now.  The $_GET function automatically passes any form variable through urldecode().  That's what appears to be messing everything up.  See my update for the ugly - but necessary - solution.  And thanks for starting me on the right track.

Comment: @Neil I'm not understanding your edit; did you mean `$bookTitle = str_replace("W5x32RS97", "'", $bookTitleTemp);` ? Can you post additional code? I'm not sure how you lose the apostrophe when you call `$_GET['booktitle']`...

Comment: You're right, sorry - typo at my end, should have been $bookTitleTemp.

Comment: @Neil See my update, also modified condition to check first word only

Answer (score 0):

in your link 
use "It\'s" 
not IT's

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove any apostrophe in the first word, then just test that the apostrophe has a lower string position than the first space. If it does, then remove it.

```
if(strpos($bookTitle,"'") < strpos($bookTitle," ")){
    $bookTitle = preg_replace('/\'/', '', $bookTitle, 1);
}
```

Comment: I know the description I wrote was really long; the whole basis of posting the links was to demonstrate that removing the apostrophe kills the search, and so does slashing it.  Google's API needs either the apostrophe, or a %27 instead of the apostrophe.  But no matter what I try to send them. those characters get stripped out.

Answer (score 0):

Desperate diseases need desperate remedies.

```
$translation = array("aint" => "ain't", "arent" => "aren't", "cant" => "can't", "cantve" => "can't've", "cause" => "'cause", "couldve" => "could've", "couldnt" => "couldn't", "couldntve" => "couldn't've", "didnt" => "didn't", "doesnt" => "doesn't", "dont" => "don't", "hadnt" => "hadn't", "hadntve" => "hadn't've", "hasnt" => "hasn't", "havent" => "haven't", "hed" => "he'd", "hedve" => "he'd've", "hell" => "he'll", "hellve" => "he'll've", "hes" => "he's", "hows" => "how's", "Id" => "I'd", "Idve" => "I'd've", "Ill" => "I'll", "Illve" => "I'll've", "Im" => "I'm", "Ive" => "I've", "isnt" => "isn't", "itd" => "it'd", "itdve" => "it'd've", "itll" => "it'll", "itllve" => "it'll've", "its" => "it's", "lets" => "let's", "maam" => "ma'am", "mightve" => "might've", "mightnt" => "mightn't", "mightntve" => "mightn't've", "mustve" => "must've", "mustnt" => "mustn't", "mustntve" => "mustn't've", "oclock" => "o'clock", "oughtnt" => "oughtn't", "oughtntve" => "oughtn't've", "shant" => "shan't", "shantve" => "shan't've", "shed" => "she'd", "shedve" => "she'd've", "shell" => "she'll", "shellve" => "she'll've", "shes" => "she's", "shouldve" => "should've", "shouldnt" => "shouldn't", "shouldntve" => "shouldn't've", "sos" => "so's", "thats" => "that's", "thered" => "there'd", "theres" => "there's", "theyd" => "they'd", "theyll" => "they'll", "theyllve" => "they'll've", "theyre" => "they're", "theyve" => "they've", "wasnt" => "wasn't", "wed" => "we'd", "well" => "we'll", "wellve" => "we'll've", "were" => "we're", "weve" => "we've", "werent" => "weren't", "whatll" => "what'll", "whatllve" => "what'll've", "whatre" => "what're", "whats" => "what's", "whatve" => "what've", "whens" => "when's", "whenve" => "when've", "whered" => "where'd", "wheres" => "where's", "whereve" => "where've", "wholl" => "who'll", "whollve" => "who'll've", "whos" => "who's", "whove" => "who've", "whys" => "why's", "willve" => "will've", "wont" => "won't", "wontve" => "won't've", "wouldve" => "would've", "wouldnt" => "wouldn't", "wouldntve" => "wouldn't've", "yall" => "y'all", "yalldve" => "y'all'd've", "yallre" => "y'all're", "yallve" => "y'all've", "youd" => "you'd", "youdve" => "you'd've", "youll" => "you'll", "youllve" => "you'll've", "youre" => "you're", "youve" => "you've", );

$bookTitle = strtr($bookTitle, $translation);
```